# Keep refreshing page until element is clickable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently attempting to get my code to keep refreshing the page until a specific element on the website becomes clickable. Sample code is provided below:

```
lolSize = False
           

while not lolSize:
      try:
          if size.is_enabled():
               driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size)
               lolSize = True
      except:
          time.sleep(1)
          driver.refresh()
```

Now if I put a value that is clickable at the exact moment of running the code, it works just fine. However, if a value that isn't clickable at the moment is used, the page does not refresh at all. Apologies if something rudimentary is incorrect with my code, I'm very much a novice in Python. Any help is appreciated, and if you need clarification regarding my issue, don't hesitate to ask! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You must handle the else condition of your if statement

```
while not lolSize:
      try:
          assert size.is_enabled()
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size)
          lolSize = True
      except:
          time.sleep(1)
          driver.refresh()
```

The assert will raise an exception if it is not true and refresh will occur in the exception handler code.

Also, I believe with the code provided, upon refresh the `is_enabled()` code will always raise an exception. You need to retrieve the size element each refresh to not have a `staleElementException`. Such exception will loop your code with `driver.refresh()` each time.

**UPDATE**
To ensure there is no element clickable, use the [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to get time to find the element

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
timeout_in_sec = 5. # how much time to check for a clickable element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_in_sec)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'yourCssPath')))
```

With code updated that gives:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_in_sec)

while not lolSize:
      try:
          size = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'yourCssPath')))
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size)
          lolSize = True
      except:
          time.sleep(1)
          driver.refresh()
```

Note that `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'yourCssPath')` needs to match the way you previously found `size`

Comment: I see, interesting. How would you recommend stopping the size element having a staleElementException in this scenario?

Comment: Just move your code that retrieve ```size = driver.find_element...``` inside the try/catch

Comment: I see, still not working for me lmao. I'm not the brightest in coding so I appreciate the help. I basically put what was retrieving the size element like you said but it just doesn't work. I had put it in the beginning of try just before `assert size.is_enabled()`

Comment: The placement for the size element is the right one. Can you clarify what is not working? Are you getting inside the exception handler or never reach that code? Is the element just never enabled.. if so you might consider using ```element_to_be_clickable from expected_conditions```

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I should have clarified a lot better there (was in a rush, sorry!). Basically the page keeps refreshing even when there is a clickable element present.

Comment: see the update portion to help you with your second issue

Comment: @AnthonyNunez have you been able to resolve the latest issue. Please don't forget to answer his answer or any other if they helped you out

Comment: Hi, sorry I’ve been busy haha. No I haven’t been able to solve the issue @NicLaforge perhaps for a bit of context, I’m attempting to develop code revolving around the Nike website. I’m not sure if I’m that incompetent in my code or if Nike is just weird. It either refreshes constantly or just doesn’t work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

My idea for this problem would be like that :

```
while True: 
   try: 
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();")
      break 
   except: 
          time.sleep(1)
          driver.refresh()
```